# Undo docker-compose down

Tags: docker, docker-compose

After doing

```
docker-compose up
```

and adding lots of stuff to the database etc, I stupidly did a

```
docker-compose down
```

to stop the dockers from running.  Just found out it actually removes it all.

Is there a way to recover from this and get back the data containers?

FYI This is the config of the datastore in docker-compose.yml:

```
services:
  jira_datastore:
    image: busybox
    volumes:
      - /data
    entrypoint: echo "PSQL Data"
```

Comment: do you want to recover your data ? or learn how to stop your containers without removing them ?

Comment: I want to recover my data!

Comment: If you stored the data in the container itself, then it's gone. This is why best practice to _never_ store data in the container itself. You should always store data in volumes, or in externally-mounted directories. https://docs.docker.com/engine/tutorials/dockervolumes/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to recover the data, so it indeed is possible, in some cases to retrieve the data.

As mentioned in the question, I had a datastore which points to /data

By doing compose-up again and after this moving the data from the old to the new volume I got everything back!

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible :-(. 
Next time do `docker-compose stop` to stop but not remove the containers. You could also save the data in a map shared on your host computer to make the data persistent, for more info on this: https://docs.docker.com/engine/tutorials/dockervolumes/

Answer (score 1):

So as per docker-compose docs (https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/compose_down) the data is not really deleted. For unnamed volumes the new up command cannot connect back to them hence ends up recreating a new volume, your old data sould still reside in DOCKER_HOME/volumes.

Found my data by looking at the change timestamp.